Why does "Lake" often come before the name of a body of water, but never "Ocean" or "River"?
Lake Tahoe. Lake Superior. Lake Erie
But never "Ocean Atlantic"?
Very occasionally, "River Nile," but never "River Amazon" or "River Missouri"?

Highly related: When to put "River" before or after its name and why?

Never River Amazon?

The River Amazon figures in the title and contents of a good number of books.

See also: Lake before or after lake name

River Thames. Conversely, there is Alpine Lake, California (and others in the state), Adirondack Lake, New York, and even Silver Lake Reservoir.

In UK rivers might be either way round – or both, such as River Tweed in Northumberland, and Tweed River in Leicestershire.

Because the gods of English decreed it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7rbVZS1Pvk We sail the ocean blue...

...and then there is the tautological River Avon, where avon means river in Celtic languages (afon in Welsh).

In the duplicate-or-is-it?, Barrie England's moderately highly upvoted answer is hedged: 'I suspect British English tends to put ...' implying that there are rules of thumb in this area, with idiomatic choices informed by regular use and mimicry, but no definitive logic.

I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a misconception.

I can't think of any Pond ______ or  Creek _______ or Canal _______.

@TimR in UK we have Pond Lye and Creek Rithe, but no canals that I can find, apart from various Canal Pond, Canal Pool and Canal Burn (which are not canals).

There's the French Canal Saint-Martin, known by that name in English, though as it's French word order it probably doesn't count any more than Canal du Midi, and nor do various US cities called Canal Fulton, Canal Winchester, etc.

Although a number of questions like yours have been closed (for different reasons) over the years, two that remain open may be of interest to you: “Lake before or after lake name” (mentioned in an earlier comment in this thread by Stuart F) and “When to put ‘River’ before or after its name and why?.”

Voting to reopen. It's not a misconception that the Amazon River is far more common than the River Amazon. But as that chart clearly shows, two centuries ago it was the opposite - it was nearly always the river Amazon in the early 1800s. Note that I included the verb is in my search terms specifically to avoid "title capitalization" skewing the results.
